# Adding back end to Ionic app to read from MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, angular, ionic-framework

I'm a junior front-end dev who is getting overwhelmed and confused by my first android app. The project was built using the Ionic CLI, and I need to to be able to read/write to a MySQL database that I have already set up. I installed the `mysql` driver and imported it into the typescript file for one of the app's pages, and it gave me an error that a StackOverflow user said meant that I can't connect to the db on the front end, and that it will need to be handled on the back end.

I've been searching for a tutorial or article about how to add a back end to an already existing ionic project, but all of the tutorials only show how to start a new node.js ionic app.

So can someone tell me explicitly what files I need to add to my already-existing ionic app, where to place them, and what code should be in those files? The current folder structure is the default Ionic CLI structure.

Comment: The backend will need to be separate to the existing ionic app, and hosted on a server somewhere where it will be accessible to the Angular app. The Angular app can then communicate via HTTP with the backend. If you want a database that doesn't need to be hosted on a server, and only needs to hold each individual user's data, look at sqlite instead

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad for anyone to provide any short and precise answers.

I think you need to read up on what an Angular app is, because it seems to me that you are mixing up some basic concepts here.

First of all, when you are accessing an Angular website your browser is actually downloading the compiled code and running it locally on your machine. It won't however download a copy of your database, this will have to be accessed over the Internet. One way of accessing a remote SQL server is through a REST api.

You should google how to create such an API with for example Node.js and Express.js. Get that working first before you start on your Angular app. You can test your API using Postman.

When you have a working backend API you google how you create an Angular app and how to create a service for accessing a REST api.

Good luck. :)